# How does customization work in tinymce

Tags: tinymce

I have a question before downloading tinymce.

Does anyone know if its possible to disable features for the users? (Example, make it so the user can only input text, not pictures)

And also, is it possible to change the style/css of the buttons and toolbar so they fit with your site?

Comment: yes it is possible please read the documentation

Answer (score 0):

You should manipulate tinymce.init() by adding or removing the unwanted plugins.
There are tons of options, so do some experimenting.
However, you should really begin with reading the [documentation](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php).